# Yii2 : Require at least one of the two fields

Tags: yii2

One of the two phone numbers **phone_parent** or **phone_students** must be provided AND they must be an integer. When combined, only atLeastValidator works, when I leave it out, the integer works. Out of ideas. Any hint?

```
[['phone_parent', 'phone_student'], 'integer'],
['phone_student', AtLeastValidator::class, 'in' => ['phone_student', 'phone_parent']],
['phone_parent', AtLeastValidator::class, 'in' => ['phone_student', 'phone_parent']],
```

update: I've just discovered that integer works **when** I try to submit (no request is sent yet, I remain on form page); However it should work on focus out - just like all the other validators; It's an instance of ActiveForm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to have that custom `AtLeastValidator`, you can use `when` and `whenClient` in the following way to work the way you want.

Your rules should look like below

```
[
    ['phone_parent'],
    'required',
    'when' => function ($model) {
        return ($model->phone_student == '');
    },
    'whenClient' => 'function(attribute,value){
        return ($("#testform-phone_student").val()=="");
    }',
    'message' => 'Either Parent or Student Phone must be filled',
],
[
    ['phone_student'],
    'required',
    'when' => function ($model) {
        return ($model->phone_parent == '');
    },
    'whenClient' => 'function(attribute,value){
        return ($("#testform-phone_parent").val()=="");
    }',
    'message' => 'Either Parent or Student Phone must be filled',
],
[['phone_parent', 'phone_student'], 'integer'],
```

Above all i would use a regular expression in order to validate the phone number to be valid rather than just using `integer` that will allow `0` as a pone number or mobile number which isnt valid. using `match`  validator with a regex in the `pattern` will make it solid.

Comment: You don't need `safe` validator when there are other validators attached to the fields.

Comment: sorry forgot to remove as i added the `integer` validator later from his code  @Bizley

Comment: Muhammad your solution works perfectly - both validators work when the field loses focus; thanks!

ps. yes sure I was going to validate against proper phone number syntax in the next step, for now I was just curious if AtLeastValidator can be combined.

The power of SO cannot be overestimated, lost half a day yesterday, didn;t want to write on SO...:)

Comment: happy to help @joey , just try to look into the docs whenever you have to add something new and try to avoid any third part extension or validators if yii already has it bundled you can trust the Yii guys for better performance , time to SCoot

Comment: for regex i use the following rule to validate a valid 10 digit us phone number `[['phone_number'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^\(?\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/', 'message' => '{attribute} is not a valid 10 digit US phone number'],`

Comment: you're right Muhammed, I didn't read into the docs **that** thoroughly, just skimed through the list of inbuilt validators and didn't see anything that seemed relevant to 'one of n'. Thanks for the regex:) ps. 'time to SCoot' - what do you mean?:) scooter riding? or some IT jargon I'm ignorant of?

Comment: haha @Joey thats just a cool way to say good bye , like **IDIOS** or **See ya later , Aligator** :P